# Why it complains in cpp file but not in header file?

Tags: c++

I have the following classes:

**MessageConstants.h:**

```
class MessageConstants
{

public:
    ...
    static const int ErrorDescriptionLength = 256;
...
};
```

**SystemMessage.h:**

```
class EvtError
{
private:
    struct MsgData
    {
        int errorCode;            
        char errorDescription[MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength]; 
    }__attribute__((packed)) msgData;

public:
    EvtError(int errorCode, string errorDescription);
    inline void setErrorDescription(string desc){memcpy(msgData.errorDescription, desc.c_str(),
                min(MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength, (int)desc.length()));}

};
```

**SystemMessage.cpp:**

```
EvtError::EvtError(int errorCode, string errorDesc)
{
    memset(&msgData, '\0', sizeof(msgData));
    msgData.errorCode = errorCode;
    memcpy(msgData.errorDescription, errorDesc.c_str(), min(MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength, (int)errorDesc.length()));
}
```

I got the following link error on  **SystemMessage.cpp** statement `memcpy(msgData.errorDescription, errorDesc.c_str(), min(MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength, (int)errorDesc.length()));` :

**In function EvtError::EvtError(int, std::string):
undefined reference to MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make:  [link] Error 1**

If I replace the `MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength` with `sizeof(msgData.errorDescription)`, the link error disappear.

My questions:

1. Why it doesn't complain the `MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength` in the **SystemMessage.h** file, where there are two places with it?
2. How to avoid above link error?

Comment: This is because const static ints in class definitions is broken because they don't have real addresses, which is required for `std::min`. I'm too tired to explain properly. `min((int)MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength` or `min(+MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength` will fix it by making a temporary copy. Alternatively, take it out of the class as a regular const, perhaps in a namespace.

Comment: @NeilKirk Dude stop posting answers in comments. Either post an answer, or don't.

Comment: you might want to null-terminate your buffer once you fix the link error

Comment: @MattMcNabb will "memset(&msgData, '\0', sizeof(msgData));" null-terminate the buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `min` is:

```
template <typename T>
const T& min(const T&, const T&);
```

It takes its inputs by reference - which requires them to have storage. Your constant:

```
static const int ErrorDescriptionLength = 256;
```

Does not currently have storage. There are two ways to approach this. First, you can just add storage in your .cpp:

```
const int MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength;
```

Second, you can just cast it to an int:

```
min((int)MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength, (int)errorDesc.length())
 // ^^^^^
```

Comment: I have tried your first solution. It will cause compile error in SystemMessage.h file: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA What? All you added was the one line in the MessageConstants.cpp right?

Comment: I removed the "= 256" from the MessageConstants.h and then add const int MessageConstants::ErrroDescriptionLength = 256; in MessageConstants.cpp. The gcc compiler will complain then.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA Leave the "= 256" in the header. Everything else has to see that value.

Comment: tried that. It will cause "duplicate" compile error.

Comment: I mean, the 256 should be ONLY in the header. The only change you should be making is adding the one line I mentioned in my answer to your cpp. The headers should be unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Static variable must have a *definition* outside the class:

```
const int MessageConstants::ErrorDescriptionLength ;
```

This should go in exactly one `.cpp`. file in your project.

Sometimes you can get away without it, but in those cases it is either because the variable was not *odr-used*, or the program was ill-formed (but ODR violations don't require diagnosis).

Comment: In theory this is the correct solution but I've found it not working in Visual Studio compilers.

Comment: @NeilKirk report a compiler bug then

Comment: I tried that, then I will get compile error in SystemMessage.h saying: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

Comment: @MattMcNabb aren't you allowed to directly define `static const` integral types in class?

Comment: @vsoftco it all comes down to *odr-use*

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA maybe you made a typo? [See it working](http://ideone.com/DFaykT)